# How to write code document architecture

Tags: coding-style

I have moved to new project and I am expected to write document which explains entire code, so that if any new developer joins project will understand code by looking at document. Code is written in C, can you please suggest technical name (I don't thing I am making design doc, am I?)  of document and how to start with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never met a document - not matter how well written - that got me to understand the code of an entire project. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would call this the "Technical Design". Normally however you would split things up into multiple documents, such as "Functional Specification", a "High Level Design" and "Low Level Design" (which together make up the Technical Design). But it of course depends on the organization you are working in.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I know about HLL and LLL but thing is I wanted to write code flow not design.. can you put any light on this.

Comment: Well, you could include high level data flow, state diagrams and control flow diagrams within the documents, but be sure you don't drop below a certain level, as it will be a lot of work, and hell to maintain. Try and find some tools to support you (UML for instance) if you want to go that deep. Inline code comments explaining *what* the code does is better for low level IMHO. The more connected the code is to the design, the better. And never underestimate class and method documentation itself; they should be part of your LLD, not separate.